# OpsCenter on AWS: No permission to create /mnt/cassandra/data directory

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Followed the instructions here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html

Installed OpsCenter on m3.large. When launching an instance, I get this error:

**Error: Start stage failed: Failed to start node [ip]: Timed out waiting for Cassandra to start.**

The log on the individual server is:

```
CassandraDaemon.java (line 235) Directory /mnt/cassandra/data doesn't exist
CassandraDaemon.java (line 239) Has no permission to create /mnt/cassandra/data directory
```

What do I need to do to let it have the permission? I use a key/secret pair that have all rights on AWS to generate more nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you create the directory `/mnt/cassandra/data` for it, as root, then `chown` it to the user that Cassandra is running as.

Alternatively, are you sure it's mounted correctly? (stuff in /mnt tends to be remote mounts)

Comment: Manually creating the directory+chown and restarting the service on each new node works, thanks. Any idea why I have to create it myself? Shouldn't it just have the permissions?

Comment: I dunno.  I didn't actually know the answer, just made an educated guess. ;)